# Reading from file using fscanf

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am trying to read a sequence of letters from an input file until the end of a line, store the letters in an array, and return the number of letters that were read in each line.

Note: I am required to use `fscanf`, `MAX_IN_LENGTH` has already been defined using `#define`, and the input file has already been opened to read.

Here is what I have:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX_IN_LENGTH; i++) {
 if (fscanf (input, "%c", &sequence[i]) != '\n')
 count++;
 }
return count;
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to read each sequence line by line

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf()` doesn't return the character it scans like you assumed. It returns the number of input items assigned, or `EOF` if it fails.

```
if (fscanf(input, "%c", &sequence[i]) != EOF) {
    if (sequence[i] == '\n') { break; }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Would all of this go inside the initial for loop?

Comment: @user3303851 Yes. The first line checks if the scan is successful, the second line checks if the scanned character is the new line character.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I tried this and it's returning the number of total letters read and not the number of letters read for each sequence.

Comment: @user3303851 Updated solution to count only the number of letters till the end of a particular line

Comment: @Joe Good job, I put the line to increment `count` at the end as I guess the new line character isn't counted according to the original program.

Comment: @YuHao Good catch. I agree

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the manual page for `fscanf`? It is online - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf

You will note that it will note return the value of the comparison that you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* fscanf, printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* realloc, free, exit, NULL */

#define MAX_IN_LENGTH 100

int read_line(FILE* strm, char buffer[]) {
   char ch;
   int items;
   int idx = 0;
   if(strm) {
      while((items = (fscanf(strm, "%c", &ch))) == 1 && idx < MAX_IN_LENGTH) {
         buffer[idx++] = ch;
      }
   }
   return idx;
}

int copy_data(char buffer[], int length, char** s) {
   static int current_size = 0;
   *s = (char*)realloc(*s, current_size + length+1); /* +1 for null terminator */
    memcpy(*s+current_size, buffer, length);
    current_size += length;
    return s ? current_size : 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   int line = 0;
   char buf[MAX_IN_LENGTH] = {0};
   char* array = 0;
   int idx = 0;
   int bytes_read = 0;
   if(argc == 2) {
       FILE* in=fopen(argv[1],"r");  
       while((bytes_read = read_line(in, buf)) > 0) {
           printf("%d characters read from line %d\n", bytes_read, ++line);
           idx = copy_data(buf, bytes_read, &array);
       }
       if(array) {
           array[idx] = '\0';
           printf("Complete string: %s\n", array);
           free(array);
       }
       fclose(in);
   }

   return 0;
}
```